# Handle library versions

Tags: ruby, versioning

I am trying to implement a library that provides an unified way to communicate to a server which is changing its API calls from version to version. I plan to implement it that way:

connect.rb:

```
class Connect
    def self.getConn(params)
        case params[:version]
            when '4.0' then return Connect4.new(params)
            when '5.0' then return Connect5.new(params)
            else 'Version not supported.'
        end

    end 
end

class Connect4
    def initialize(params)
        # Code for v4.
    end 
end

class Connect5
    def initialize(params)
        # Code for v5.
    end 
end
```

test.rb:

```
require 'connect'

conn = Connect.getConn(:version => '4.0')

puts conn
```

I think it would work, but i'm still new to ruby and there might be issues i'm not considering. Is there any best practice to handle these kind of 'challenge'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach, it could certainly work. On the other hand, if you have multiple entry points to your API then passing the version to every one of them feels kinda ugly. You could solve it with some global setting but let's not go there...

[Twitter's Cassandra](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra) gem has an interesting approach, instead of passing the version number, you require a different sublibrary ([docs](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra#cassandra-version)):

```
require 'cassandra' # default version
require 'cassandra/1.0' # 1.0 version
```

This is especially useful when used with [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) because you can select the version like this

```
gem "cassandra", require: "cassandra/1.0"
```

and you are done for the whole application.

Comment: melanie93, consider marking Jiri's answer as your solution if they were able to help you.